# Print rows with individual max date in Mysql

Tags: mysql

```
customer_i       fundamt      installment          date_time
41                 115        1054                 2014-05-27  
42                 116        1067                 2014-07-27  
41                 117        1089                 2014-07-30  
42                 118        1120                 2014-07-30   
43                 118        1120                 2014-08-30   
42                 118        1120                 2014-08-30   
41                 118        1120                 2014-06-30   
43                 118        1120                 2014-02-30
```

I want like this:

```
customer_id        fundamt    installment          date_time
41                 117        1089                 2014-07-30
42                 118        1120                 2014-08-30 
43                 118        1120                 2014-08-30
```

Row that contain max date_time:

PLease help me writing SQL in Mysql

Comment: no , i asked only when not able to write it. It might be easier for you but not for all.

Answer (score 1):

After going through thoroughly your question realized the actual requirement. This might be simple query, easier to read and maintain.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE (customer_id, date_time) IN ( SELECT customer_id, MAX(date_time) FROM test GROUP BY customer_id ) 
ORDER BY customer_id
```

**Edit**

Other option I can think of is left join the table with itself.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM your_table a
LEFT JOIN your_table b ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id AND a.date_time < b.date_time
WHERE b.customer_id IS NULL
```

Comment: the thing is that this is good for less rows not for large rows. I mean millions of rows .So it cant help me.

Comment: There are two possible ways I can think of to fetch the required output. I've also added another query for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a in clause with subselect

```
SELECT customer_id, fundamt, installment, date_time
FROM your_table
where ( customer_id, date_time)  in (select customer_id , max(date_time) 
                      FROM your_table  
                      GROUP BY customer_id  )
```